# A new warning appears in COLAB

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, stable-diffusion

I have a warning on google colab because I use stable-diffusion-webui, but I was told that it is not a problem if I pay the bill.
To this person. (Chris Perry @thechrisperry)
But the warning has changed,

You may be executing code that is disallowed which may terminate your runtime without warning. Colab prioritizes interactive notebook compute and Colab prioritizes interactive notebook compute and disallows some types of usage when executing code without compute units as outlined in the FAQ.

Your compute unit balance is 0.

I am getting a message saying "Your compute unit balance is 0.
Is it possible that even if I am paying for the service, if my points reach 0, I will be subject to a warning?

I contacted google and they replied that the only support they can provide is a refund.
I am out of luck every time.

Comment: Compute Units are from Colab Pro or their pay-as-you-go scheme, [options shown here](https://colab.research.google.com/signup). It seems that they are detecting the code as requiring resources that may utilise resources that cost these units. I've no idea who you're referencing as Chris Perry, and you also may want to consider running the code directly on your machine instead.